# How to implement add method from List interface

Tags: java, list, addition, implementation

I want to implement the add method for my Customlist which implements List in java. The code looks like this:

```
public class CustomList implements List{
    private List list;
    public boolean add(Object s) {
        boolean check = false;
        try {
            System.out.println("LOG: now performing the addition of an object");
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            check = list.add(s);
            long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            System.out.println(estimatedTime);
            System.out.println();
        }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return check;
    }

    public CustomList(List l) {
        list = l;
    }
}
```

However, when I use it in my main method, it doesn't work. It seems that Only my list in Customlist actually adds new Object, but in main method, it does not. How can I solve this problem, thanks.
Here is the main method in class TestCases:

```
public class TestCases {
    private static CustomList t = new CustomList(new ArrayList());
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        t.add("abcd");
        for(Object temp : t) {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Updated: I've just included a for each loop for testing, but it won't print anything and I got Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: How do you know it does not add object to `t`?

Comment: Post your actual code with all the methods. How are you checking the list contents in your main method?

Comment: I use for each loop to print out the String in t but I got null pointer exception .

Comment: @DN96 I think you should not implement List you shoud extends ArrayList

Comment: You haven't shown the remaining methods. Your iterator() method is probably wrong. Note that List is a generic type. Since Java 5, more than 10 years ago.

Comment: @JBNizet Intellij automatically import all the methods in List and I don't modify them, just override the add method.

Comment: @LPGAD But my teacher want me to implements from List

Comment: Then how could your list work? You can't just expect a list to work if you just implement one of its methods. Adding 4 wheels to a chassis doesn't make a car.

Comment: @DN96 When you overrides the iterator method in the List .foreach is dead.you overrids add method .Size is always zero.

Comment: @DN96When you overrides the List , many of the original structures are destroyed

Comment: @JBNizet So I think that I should extends the ArrayList not implements the List?

Comment: @LPGAD What if I use ArrayList instead of List?

Comment: No, I wouldn't even recomment implementing List. Especially given your current level of understanding.

Comment: @DN96 you should use ArrayList but you should not overrides any method~~

Comment: @JBNizet So, how can I solve this problem, by extending array list? Because my professor wants me to use decorator pattern

Comment: if you use decorator pattern . you can write yourself interface . and implements your interface .you do not destory List  or try to overrides any method .

Comment: @LPGAD But he wants me to use List interface

Comment: Then I would do what you did, but also implement all the missing methods of the List interface.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for your solution. I've implemented all mising methods and now it runs smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomList<E> extends ArrayList<E>{
    List list;

    public CustomList(List l) {
        list = l;
    }
}
```

**Test the code**

```
 public class TestCases {
        private static CustomList t = new CustomList(new ArrayList());
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            t.add("abcd");
            System.out.println(t.size());
            for(Object temp : t) {
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

**operation result:**

```
1
abcd
```

When you overrides the List method in the list of the original add iterator method all destroyed so I think it is best not to overrides these methods.
If you are interested in viewing the List source code

Comment: Thanks, but my professor wants the add method to have some more functionailitis like prints out the execution time and the statement: "LOG: now performing the addition of an object". How can I do this without override the add method?